# Insert Select with REGEXP_LIKE for 10Mn+ records running slow

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, sql-insert, large-data

Question is on Oracle 11g, Exadata.

I have a large staging table (10mn+ rows)with a column that shows transaction description of where a transaction happened like

```
TRANSACTION_DESCRIPTION
_______________________
KMART 19028    New jers
JC Penny 32f8d New Jers
KMARTStore 23101xg  Los Ang
JCPenny       Austin
Amazon Prime   Calif
MACYS        DALLAS
```

I have a reference table aggregating individual store to their parent company. I can get any variation of the individual store like JC Penny or JCPENNY or jcpenny.

The reference store table looks like

```
Store_to_Search      Aggregator_Store
_____________________________________
JC Penny             JCPenny
JCPENNY              JCPenny
JCPenny              JCPenny
Macy                 Macy's
Macys                Macy's
Macy's               Macy's
```

I find the Store_to_search on the Transaction_description to find matching aggregator. I'm not interested in anything else in the Transaction_description  field.
This is the join condition.

```
ON REGEXP_LIKE(T.TRAN_DESCRIPTION, '(^)' || S.STORE_TO_SEARCH )
```

Both Transaction_Description & Store_to_Search are Indexed, non-unique.

Running a select returns the data in about 5-6 mins. If I remove this dimension table, then I get the result in about 1-2 mins.

However, inserting into final FACT table takes anywhere above 2-3 hrs. That is unacceptable.

The fact table does not have any indexes at the time of insert. There are no partitions as well in Fact table.

I'd like some suggestions on how I can improve -

- the inserts (use hints?)
- the whole concept - is there a better way to achieve what I want to achieve?

Plus -I am not an Oracle person. More of SQL Server, this is a proof of principle if we can move to Oracle used by another team.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: *I get the result in about 1-2 mins* - is this really a time to fetch all the values or to fetch just the first few rows? Execute your insert with `gather_plan_statistics` hint then check executed plan with: `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format => 'ALL ALLSTATS LAST))`

Comment: Thanks @astentx Good point.
It returns first 50 using SQL Developer.

I'll have to read how to do the next 2 things you mentioned. I'll get back.

Comment: Please provide the actual query you are using for the insert

Answer (score 0):

after long hours of deliberation and google searches, I have decide to be smart about it.

Rather than inserting the data in the FACT table, I've used the join to reference table in the VIEW of the FACT table that will be used in my cube. It is fast if I properly Index it.

Thank you all